# Python Flask App - File can send using 'send_from_directory' but the updated file contents are not shown the client side

Tags: python-2.7, flask

Developed a web application using python flask and it had the following functionalities,

1. User can enter the inputs.
2. Once inputs are received, flask app do the tasks like,
       - Login to a VM and do the tasks. Used paramiko module for SSH to the remote machine.
       - Then the captured result is saved into a text file in the host machine.
       - And then send the file to the client using send_from_directory ()

At the client side, user can view the input form and once user click the generate button, flask app do the task and the output text file can send to the client side. The issue here, at the client side looks like some cache happening as if the output file in server side is changed, the client side that change will not reflect instead the earlier contents of the file still shows to the user.

My code snippet is given below,

```
53 #View the results captures.
54 @app.route("/view")
55 def view():
56         return render_template("view.html")
57 
58 #Download file.
59 @app.route('/static/<path:filename>/',methods=['GET','POST'])
60 def download_file (filename):
61         try:
62                 return send_from_directory 
(directory=static,filename=filename)
63 
64         except Exception as e:
65                 return str(e)
```

view.html

```
 1 <!doctype html>
 2 <html>
 3    <body>
 4         {% with messages = get_flashed_messages() %}
 5          {% if messages %}
 6             <ul>
 7                {% for message in messages %}
 8                <li>{{ message }}</li>
 9                {% endfor %}
10             </ul>
11          {% endif %}
12       {% endwith %}
13 
14       <h1>Your result is ready.</h1>
15       <a href = "/static/bt_output.txt" target="_blank"><button 
  class='btn btn-default'>View Result!</button></a>
16 
17 <!--      <p>Do you want to <a href = "{{ url_for('main') }}">
18            <b>View Result</b></a></p>-->
19 
20 
21    </body>
22 </html>
23
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Update, another approach...

Add a timestamp function to Jinja (e.g. in your init.py):

```
def get_timestamp():
    return int(time.time())

app.jinja_env.globals['timestamp'] = get_timestamp
```

And change your HTML to this:

```
<a href="/static/bt_output.txt?time={{ timestamp() }}" target="_blank">
    <button class='btn btn-default'>View Result!</button>
</a>
```

#### Original Answer

You can use [response.cache_control](http://werkzeug.pocoo.org/docs/0.11/datastructures/#werkzeug.datastructures.RequestCacheControl) to make file/route specific changes to any of the cache control headers, otherwise you should look to your server settings for defaults.

```
@app.route('/static/<path:filename>/',methods=['GET','POST'])
def download_file (filename):
    try:
        response = send_from_directory(directory=static,
                                       filename=filename)
        response.cache_control.max_age = 60  # e.g. 1 minute
        return response

     except Exception as e:
             return str(e)
```

You should also look at the `SEND_FILE_MAX_AGE_DEFAULT` [configuration setting](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/config/)

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. But still the issue is not recovered, I've added the option like  `response.headers['Cache-Control'] = 'no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate'` and `response.cache_control.max_age = 0`,`response.cache_control.public = True`. And when we run the application first time, the outfile contents properly shown in the client side, but again we give different input, the result text file still showing the contents in the previous run, at the server side we could see the output text file is properly updated but from the client side, that change is not affected.

Comment: Thank you very much for the support.